# Automating ArcMap topology summary report

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I am trying to automate a topology check process in ArcMap. As the last step, I hope to generate the error report automatically rather than clicking the 'generate summary' and 'Export to file' buttons manually. Is it feasible to automate with arcpy...?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to export features representing the errors? There is a GP tool Export Topology Errors for this. Or do you want to export a text file with information about errors?

Comment: Hi Alex, I hope to generate the text file only. Do you know any methods?

Comment: For text, you sadly cannot do this using `arcpy`. If you can install `comtypes` package, I could post the code you need to run to call ArcObjects COM objects under the hood.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your advice. I do not have experience in ArcObjects. Do you think it will be complicated process for non-experienced user?

Comment: Not really. You would need to install `comtypes` Python package and follow some instructions on downloading some extra Python files. I understand that for a non-Python person this can be overwhelming. You may start looking here https://tereshenkov.wordpress.com/2016/01/16/accessing-arcobjects-in-python/ and ask a specific question here on GIS.SE if you stuck somewhere. Good luck!

Comment: Did you ever get this to work with ArcObjects, or with out ArcObjects, as I am looking to do the exact same thing ?